# Create-react-app build failing on heroku when using absolute paths

Tags: heroku, create-react-app

When using absolute paths in my CRA, the build step fails on heroku.

> NODE_PATH=src/

Is in my .env.local file and also use this env var in my heroku settings.
I try to build my app on heroku using the "heroku-postbuild" script (which just runs "react-scripts build". I am using an express server to serve this build folder and to proxy requests to various API's.

this is the error I get:

> remote:        Running heroku-postbuild (yarn) remote:        yarn run
>   v1.14.0 remote:        $ react-scripts build remote:        Creating
>   an optimized production build... remote:        Failed to compile.
>   remote: remote:        ./src/app/App.js remote:        Cannot find
>   module: 'checklist/Checklist'. Make sure this package is installed.
>   remote: remote:        You can install this package by running: yarn
>   add checklist/Checklist. remote: remote: remote: error Command failed
>   with exit code 1.

the Checklist.js file is located under: "src/checklist/Checklist.js"

Any idea what I need to do to make this work?

Comment: any luck with this? same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it seemed to be a result of my local file having a different casing than the one committed to git. i.e. if you have a file `Checklist.js` committed to git and are trying to `import checklist from 'checlist/checklist.js'`, run `git mv [...]/checklist.js [...]/Checklist.js`.

See [this issue comment](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/issues/71#issuecomment-385723967) for the original answer that got me here.

Answer (score -2):

Just create a jsconfig.json file on the root of your project and paste this(if you use src as the starting point for your absolute imports

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```